# Trouble with Pizza Shop function in python

Tags: python

I'm having problems with my code for a pizza shop [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m3Xo.png),

Below is one of the example inputs that the grader would pass through the function

```
>>>cost_calculator([], ["ham", "anchovy"], drinks=["tub", "tub"], coupon=0.1)
35.61
```

[] represents a pizza, and the second ["ham", "anchovy"] is a pizza with toppings.

One of the main things that confuses me is how I would represent [] as pizza, which costs $13. I have a dictionary placeholder, but that doesn't work beause [] isn't hashable. Another problem I'm facing is how I would deal with the toppings, that are somehow contained inside of the list. My function signature is also incorrect, I've had that issue multiple times in the past, if somebody could point me in the direction of a resource explaining them, I'd be very grateful. I'm fairly confident in my dictionary usage however.

```
def cost_calculator(x,wings,drinks,coupon): 
    total_cost = 0
    x = {[]:13}
    Price_of_drinks = {"small": 2.00, "medum":3.00,"large":3.50,"tub":3.75}
    Price_of_wings = {10:5.00,20:9.00,40:17.50,100:48.00}
    Price_of_toppings = {"pepperoni":1.00,"mushroom":0.50,"olive":0.50,"anchovy":2.00,"ham":1.50}
    if x in iter
        total_cost += x[[]]
        if "pepperoni" in x
            total_cost += 1.00
        if "mushroom" in x
            total_cost += 0.50
        if "olive" in x
            total_cost += 0.50
        if "anchovy" in x
            total_cost += 2.00
        if "ham" in x
            total_cost += 1.50
    if wings in iter
        total_cost += Price_of_wings['wings']
    if drinks in iter:
        total_cost += Price_of_drinks['drinks']
    if wings in iter:
        total_cost += Price_of_wings['wings']
    if coupon in iter
        total_cost= total_cost - (total_cost*coupon)
    total_cost *= 1.0625
    round(total_cost,2)
    return total_cost
```

I'm just looking for a pointer in the right direction, and be sure to edit if you feel my questions are off. I understand that my knowledge is very basic, so a pointer means a lot.

Comment: Can you explain WHY your cost is 35.61?, because I see this as a pizza  (13$) with HAM (1.5$) + Anchovies (2.0$) + 2 tubs (3.75 X 2) which does not equal 35.61

Comment: @Abhishek That's an example, it's got
1. Pizza
2.Pizza but with Ham and Anchovy
3. 2 drinks, both tub
4. a 10% coupon
I've put in prices, and I think I got how coupons work, but the rest is muddled, especially pizza, how would I be able to pull a price for an empty list?

Comment: So it's 13 + 1.5 + 2 + (3.75 X 2) yes?

Comment: Can your empty [] have MORE than 1 pizza?

Comment: It's 13+(1.5+2+13)+(3.75*2), with a 10% coupon

Comment: I don't think so, it represents one pizza, [] is a single pizza, and you can include toppings inside the list

Comment: check if my code works!

Comment: I think it does, but I just gotta take a minute to understand it. Thank you!

Comment: You can upvote it too if you're happy! :p

Comment: @user997048.. You seem to have unmarked the answer. What happened?

Answer (score 0):

```
def cost_calculator(x, wings, drinks, coupon): 
    total_cost = 0

    Price_of_drinks = {"small": 2.00, "medum":3.00,"large":3.50,"tub":3.75}
    Price_of_wings = {10:5.00,20:9.00,40:17.50,100:48.00}
    Price_of_toppings = {"pepperoni":1.00,"mushroom":0.50,"olive":0.50,"anchovy":2.00,"ham":1.50}
    Price_of_pizza = {"mypizza":13}
```

Iterate over the list `x`, I'm referring to each element in `x` as `pizza`.

```
    for pizza in x:

        total_cost += Price_of_pizza[pizza] #Single pizza alone

    print("Cost after adding single pizza with no topping: ", total_cost) #13

    total_cost += Price_of_pizza[pizza] #Going to add pizza price and then toppings in the next loop you see

    print("Cost after adding another single pizza with topping whose price is going to be added later ", total_cost) #13 + 13

    for topping in wings:

        total_cost += Price_of_toppings[topping]

    print("Cost after adding single pizza with no topping + single pizza with two toppings requested ", total_cost) #13 + 13 + 1 + 2

    for drinksize in drinks:

        total_cost += Price_of_drinks[drinksize]

    print("Cost after adding drinks ", total_cost) #13 + 13 + 1 + 2 + 3.75 + 3.75 = 37.0

    total_cost = total_cost - total_cost*coupon #37.0 - 37.0*0.1 = 33.3

    print("Cost after discount ", total_cost)




    round(total_cost,2)
    return total_cost


cost_calculator(['mypizza'], ["ham", "anchovy"], drinks=["tub", "tub"], coupon=0.1)
```